# How to find an element and its attribute of XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a `catalog.xml` file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<thredds:catalog xmlns:thredds="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:bes="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/bes/1.0#">  
    <thredds:service name="dap" serviceType="OPeNDAP" base="/opendap/hyrax" /> 
    <thredds:service name="file" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/opendap/hyrax" /> 
    <thredds:dataset name="/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278" ID="/opendap/hyrax/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278/">
        <thredds:dataset name="MOD08_D3.A2013278.051.2013298172452.hdf" ID="/opendap/hyrax/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278/MOD08_D3.A2013278.051.2013298172452.hdf">
            <thredds:dataSize units="bytes">101753426</thredds:dataSize> 
            <thredds:date type="modified">2013-10-25T17:38:24</thredds:date> 
            <thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/allData/51/MOD08_D3/2013/278/MOD08_D3.A2013278.051.2013298172452.hdf" /> 
        </thredds:dataset>
    </thredds:dataset>
</thredds:catalog>
```

I tried to get it as:

```
//Create the XmlDocument.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("d:\\km\\catalog.xml");
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("dataset name");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
}
```

but values are not printed. I tried to parse XML like this:

```
var str8 = XElement.Parse("D:\\km\\catalog.xml");
var str1 = XElement.Parse(str8);
var result = str1.Element("thredds:dataset").
       Where (x => x.Element("serviceName").Value.Equals("dap")).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

but  it did not succeed.

I need to get name of the file from 
`thredds:dataset name="MOD08_D3.A2013278.051.2013298172452.hdf`

Can any one suggest an answer to me?

for more namespaces how to assign these attribute name?
example:

```
    thredds:catalog    xmlns:thredds="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:bes="http://xml.opendap.org/ns/bes/1.0#">
<thredds:service name="dap" serviceType="OPeNDAP" base="/opendap/hyrax"/>
<thredds:service name="file" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/opendap/hyrax"/>
<thredds:service name="wms" serviceType="WMS" base="/ncWMS/wms"/>
<thredds:dataset name="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/">
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3003100</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-03T06:48:48</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0101_v003-2014m0103t013658.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3030178</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-04T05:49:18</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0102_v003-2014m0104t004027.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
<thredds:dataset name="OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5" ID="/opendap/hyrax/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5">
<thredds:dataSize units="bytes">3019723</thredds:dataSize>
<thredds:date type="modified">2014-01-05T06:49:33</thredds:date>
<thredds:access serviceName="dap" urlPath="/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5"/>
<thredds:access serviceName="wms" urlPath="?DATASET=lds/HDF-EOS5/Aura_OMI_Level3/OMTO3e.003/2014/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0103_v003-2014m0105t013415.he5&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"/>
</thredds:dataset>
```

Comment: There is no `serviceName` or `dap` or `dataset name` in your XML.

Comment: i  have copied entire file but in formating may got deleted.

Comment: @CharlesMager there is now.

Comment: So how do you differentiate between the two `dataset` elements? Do you always want the second one?  Will there always be two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 'qualified name' consists of two parts: a local name and a namespace.  As namespaces are quite verbose, this is simplified by declaring a prefix for the namespace.

So, you're looking for what you can see is `thredds:dataset`.  The prefix used here is `thredds`, which is a prefix for the namesapce `http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0`.  So you need to find elements with that name:

```
XNamespace thredds = "http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0";
XName dataset = thredds + "dataset";
```

This should then work to get you the second `dataset` element's `name` attribute:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\to\file.xml");

var name = doc.Descendants(dataset)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"))
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KW72sz) for a working example.

Comment: when i tried for the above solution, .where is not recognized.    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;    are used

Comment: No idea - see the fiddle in the answer which shows this works.

Comment: thank you so much charles. it is working if i take as costant string.but xml content i have to take it as a file. what ever you have given in fiddle is working there is no doubt in it.but i have to download file as it is from http link daily and use it.Thats why i need to parse it. while parsing,"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." exception is coming. is there any problem in xml file.?

Comment: Thanks all. the problem is in xml first line.     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  I removed it from the file and tried again.It is now working.

Comment: once again with question, how to assign the same attribute name to a string array for more namespaces.

Comment: Not sure I follow. It may be worth asking a new question.